# How to test component with a @Inject text in the constructor in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Angular 6, I declare some injected variables in the constructor of my component, But I don't know how to configure the injected value in the unit test file, when I run `ng test`and it gives the following error:

> Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[title]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[title]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for title!

//My component

```
export class ConfirmModalComponent extends BaseModal implements OnInit {
  choosedCandidates: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(
      @Inject('title') public title,//injected variable
      protected modalService: ModalService
  ) {
      super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ....
}
//spec file of my component
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DelInterviewerConfirmModalComponent ],
      imports: [ CheckboxModule, TranslateModule ],
      providers: [ 
        { provide: title, useValue: 'modal title' },
        ModalService, 
        RequisitionDetailService ],
    schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
  })
.compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DelInterviewerConfirmModalComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.title = "test";
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I wonder if anybody meets the same problem and how to resolve the errors, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Values like dates, numbers and string must be wrapped into an [Injection Token](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#injectiontoken-objects).

1.: Create an injection token:

```
export const TITLE = new InjectionToken<string>('title');
```

2.: Inject like you do now:

```
constructor(@Inject(TITLE) private title: string)
```

3.: In your test, mock it using the InjectionToken:

```
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DelInterviewerConfirmModalComponent ],
      imports: [ CheckboxModule, TranslateModule ],
      providers: [ 
        { provide: TITLE, useValue: 'modal title' },
```